# NotFoundHttpException when trying to access image

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

I'm trying to load an image from:

```
<img ng-src="uploads/media/image.png" src="uploads/media/image.png">
```

But I get the above error, as there is no route set in `routes.php`. How do I tell laravel just to deliver the asset rather than try to route it?

Edit: additionally, if I visit `/uploads`, I get the error:

```
The requested resource /uploads was not found on this server.
```

All other assets (js/css/img) are working fine. What's different about the uploads directory?

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure the asset exists under the `public` folder. So, if you use your `src` attribute as `uploads/media/image.png`, make sure the image is located on `public/uploads/media/image.png`.

Comment: That is what I've done. For some reason, it's not delivering it correctly.

Comment: Are you using Apache or nginx?

Comment: This is in development, so it's the Laravel development server.

Comment: Homestead? Or `artisan serve`?

Comment: It's via `artisan serve`.

Comment: I've given additional information in my original post.

Answer (score 1):

I know this topic is from more than one year ago but I ran into a similar problem and got here. I finally got it to work for me by changing the *.htaccess* file;

In your case you may add the following line before any other rewrite rule in your *.htaccess*:

```
RewriteRule ^(uploads) - [L]
```

Hope this helps.